# Privately hosted Teamcity and Bitbucket Cloud Integration

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket

We have a teamcity local instance running and a bitbucket cloud instance. 
I have configured the connection correctly and I can see that teamcity has accessed via the oath several times.

In teamcity it allows me to login and says to refresh after the successful login but it just cycles through the login again.

No clue what is wrong
[image]

@LukeP helped me with the first issue , now theres a second[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3omv.png)

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I've literally just had the same issue and it was caused by login details in TC being set right for it to login, but when I was signing in for the first time to generate auth token I was using my own credentials and not the ones used by TC. Initially I was already logged in so I didn't even know what user I was confirming oauth as.

Comment: Thanks for that , that sorted it and now I have a new problem